# Visual Studio 2019 ASP.Net Core 3.1 Start Server for Use with Postman

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I want to experiment with Postman to call a webservice I've written in Visual Studio 2019 (Core 3.1).  It's the default WeatherForecast.  When I do a Debug Start or just Start (F5), I see the brower open up, and it asks me to download the resulting JSON file, and then I can open it in Visual Studio.

My question is - how do I keep the server running so I can use it with Postman?  Do I have to deploy to IIS first?

I'm following a YouTube video, but he's using VSCode.  Can you also help explain how the Kestrel or whatever webserver differs between VSCode and Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [good tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) which covers creating a project and testing with Postman.

Underneath the IDE, the same `dotnet run` process is invoked, which starts the webserver at a port you then query against. The IDE may open a browser simultaneously as convenience, but that is separate from the running server. No separate deployment or IIS needed.

Comment: Thanks, but that was essentially what I was doing, see my answer in case you have anything to add.  I am in the habit of doing "Debug Start" (Alt-DS) and I think that closes the server/window.

Comment: Gotcha. You seem to be implying that F5 alone causes the server to stop, but that's not the case in my experience. VS will stop it if tied to a closed browser window (if configured), but it runs until you stop debugging otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

Use "Start Without Debugging" (Ctrl+F5) instead of "Start Debug" (F5).

When debugging, the server closes automatically.  When choosing the 'Without Debugging" option the command windows running the server stays open, allowing the developer to try Postman or another browser, etc...